# Why is compiling my Closure code with Plovr giving me weird symbols?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, plovr

I ran `java -jar ~/PlovrFiles/plovr.jar build ~/js/config.js > /tmp/compiled.js`

However, the Closure compiler issues a bizarre error with weird symbols such as `RPP?LQ?RP*)?K??,)I?S??$?d?$?`.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected literal value near ??*??RPP?LQ?RP*)?K??,)I?S??$?d?$? ???
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:64)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:44)
    at org.plovr.ConfigParser.createBuilderFromFile(ConfigParser.java:29)
    at org.plovr.ConfigParser.parseFile(ConfigParser.java:98)
    at org.plovr.cli.BuildCommand.runCommandWithOptions(BuildCommand.java:55)
    at org.plovr.cli.BuildCommand.runCommandWithOptions(BuildCommand.java:31)
    at org.plovr.cli.AbstractCommandRunner.runCommand(AbstractCommandRunner.java:41)
    at org.plovr.cli.Command.execute(Command.java:47)
    at org.plovr.cli.Main.mainWithExitCode(Main.java:56)
    at org.plovr.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected literal value near ??*??RPP?LQ?RP*)?K??,)I?S??$?d?$? ???
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1111)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.readLiteral(JsonReader.java:1079)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextValue(JsonReader.java:808)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.quickPeek(JsonReader.java:382)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:340)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:59)
    ... 9 more
t.js
```

At first, I thought these symbols were due to the hidden cache files produced by my text editor JEdit. However, deleting those files did not do away with this error. None of the files in my path seem to have these symbols. Any advice on where I could look to debug this error?

Here is my simple `config.js` file.

```
// File: config.js
{
  "id": "myApp",
  "paths": ".",
  "inputs": "mainengine.js"
}
```

Comment: Wait, are "paths" in the config file relative to the location of the config file?

Comment: Yes, your config file is including all JavaScript files in the same directory (and subdirectories) as config.js since `paths` is set to `.`

Comment: Hmm, thank you. It should be working then... maybe I should tinker with character encoding. They should be UTF-8 though...

Comment: The first thing to verify is that config.js is UTF-8 encoded since the Java stack trace indicates that the error is happening when plovr attempts to parse the JSON in the config file.

Comment: I found it! config.js was using UTF-8, but JEdit has a subtle save action titled "Gzip on disk" under buffer options, which oddly introduces lines of weird characters into my code. Thanks for your help cpeisert! In general, I really appreciate your guidance with Google Closure :D

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working.

Comment: What an unusual save option... No bad, but unusual.